# Angularjs show selected option from ng-repeat value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have drop down inside ng-repeat as follows.

```
<div ng-model="list in lists">
<div>
   <select ng-model="pType" ng-options="c.name in projType"></select>  
   <option value="{{list.value}"></option> 
</div>
```

My Controller is

```
    App.controller('pOverCtrl', function ($scope, pOverRepository, $location) {
        $scope.lists = projOverRepository.query();

        $scope.projType = [
            { value: '0', name: 'None Selected' },
            { value: '1', name: 'Construction' },
            { value: '2', name: 'Maintenance' },
        ];
})
```

The dropdown gets populated fine. But my goal is that when ng-repeat is executed it automatically shows the value that is coming from lists scope as selected. 
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.pType` should have the selected value as it's bind by ng-model.

Read the docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

And if you already have the selected value in $scope.lists, you can use the [ngSelected](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive.

Answer (score 2):

use the diretive `ng-selected`

```
<div ng-model="list in lists">
   <select ng-model="pType" ng-options="c.name in projType">                    
        <option ng-selected="list.value == list.selected" value="{{list.value}"></option> 
   </select>  

</div>
```

assuming that list.selected variable contains the value of the option selects

Comment: It didnt work. Basically I am trying to populate the dropdown than show as selected the option that is coming from database.